# cannot see the file 'SDL2.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, development-environment, sdl-2

This question is not a duplicate of [cannot open file 'SDL2.lib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419083/cannot-open-file-sdl2-lib) which discusses this same error but my problem is that I don't have an SDL2.lib file, if I can just see it I can make this work

I'm trying to set up the development environment for SDL2 by following Lazy Foo's tutorial.
[Setting up SDL 2 on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php)

The tutorial is for Visual Studio 2010, I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition 2017. Is that a problem?

The problem starts when linking the libraries, there is no x86 or x64 folder inside the lib directory of SDL2's Windows Development libraries that I downloaded from [SDL version 2.0.8 (stable)](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php).

So I specified it as `lib/` instead of `lib/x86` as it says in the tutorial.

These are the files inside the `lib` folder

```
$ ls
cmake/     libSDL2.dll.a  libSDL2_test.a   libSDL2main.a   pkgconfig/
libSDL2.a  libSDL2.la     libSDL2_test.la  libSDL2main.la
```

When building VS2017 is throwing an error saying that `Cannot open file 'SDL2.lib'`. Yeah, there is no such file. Do I need to do an additional step to get this file?

When I configured for CodeBlocks it works fine. What exactly am I doing wrong here? This may have an obvious answer but I'm not able to find it.

Comment: Tell us what's inside that sdl2 zip, especially under the lib dir

Comment: How about just using NuGet to add sdl2 to your project? Menu [Tools] -> [NuGet Package Manager] -> [Manage NuGet Packages for Solution ...] ... [Browse] search for "sdl2" click the first result and in the pane to the right select your project and hit "Install".

Comment: @JohanBoulé added the filenames to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library name `libSDL2.dll.a' indicates that it is not meant for use with VS C++ ( for dynamic link you need dll + lib, for static link you need only the lib ). You can construct a lib file from dll using dumpbin.exe and lib.exe. Your options are:

1) Download SDL source file in zip format from GitHub and create you own binaries.

2) Use vcpkg and install in just one command line ( recommended).

3) Download the SDL binaries from internet. ( you can have linker issues if the project configurations doesn't matches yours)

Comment: Looking at the SDL download page he posted, he just used the wrong binaries, there are two downloads for windows, one for msvc, one for gcc mingw.

Comment: Yeah.. Instead of the VC package I used the mingw which I previously used for codeblocks. And his answer helped me identify that.